# What can my stubbed method return to simulate a real response from the Stripe gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stripe-payments

If I want to create a stub using rspec, I'd typically do this:

`allow(my_object).to receive(:my_method).and_return("something else")`

The JSON responses from Stripe's ruby gem have a wrapper around the JSON response, like:

```
[108] pry(main)> Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_NF2qXZzjMAfqMr")
=> #<Stripe::Customer:0x12cf0 id=cus_NF2qXXXXXXX> JSON: {
  "id": "cus_NF2qXXXXXXX",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "address": {"city":"SF","country":"United States","line1":"2C","line2":null,"postal_code":"11111","state":"CA"},
  "balance": 0,
  "created": 1674752223,
  "currency": null,
  "default_currency": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": "My Customer",
  "discount": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "test_clock": null,
  # ... lots more fields
}
```

How can I construct this return value if I'm testing code that interacts with the Stripe API?

Calling `new` on the stripe object's class (e.g. `Stripe::Customer.new(field1: x, field2: y)` does not work:

```
[111] pry(main)> Stripe::Customer.new(email: 'my@randomemail.com').email
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<Stripe::Customer:0x12d2c> JSON: {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: based on comments below there is an improved solution:

```
allow(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:create).and_return(
  Stripe::Customer.construct_from(
    email: 'my@randomemail.com'
  )
)
```

Comment: Seems you could also use [`StripeObject::construct_from`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/990792f9c16472e97aa6b9c6e3993e59a01cbd3a/lib/stripe/stripe_object.rb#L85) e.g. `Stripe::Customer.construct_from(email: 'my@randomemail.com')` which I think is a bit more communicative and is basically what `convert_to_stripe_object` does anyway. Also seems to be the stripe preferred means of object testing https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/search?p=2&q=construct_from

Comment: Agree that `construct_from` will be the recommended route here. You can also leverage Stripe Mock (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock) if it is sufficient for your testing.

Comment: Thanks! That does seem better, I updated my answer